# replace figure with value from var

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael, justgage

I have a function and I have to set some options in it:

```
var g4 = new JustGage({
  id : "g4",
  value : (0, 200),
  min : 0,
  max : 500,
  title : "Facebook likes",
  showMinMax : false
});
```

From another function I get the counter of my likes:

```
function(data) {
  var likes = (data[0].fan_count );
});
```

No I want to replace the max. value, 200 to the value of the var likes.

```
value : (0, 200),
```

My solution `value : (0, {likes}),` don't work.

What is wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: That function sets the variable `likes` within the function and therein makes the value of `likes` local to the scope of the `function`, you must return the data from the function, `return likes`, or set the variable `likes` outside of the scope of that function, and assign it to the global `likes` variable by doing `likes = (data[0].fan_count);` without assigning the `var` to the local scope of the function.

Comment: o.k. I´ve tried to do this: likes = (data[0].fan_count );  and  value : (0, likes), with no success / exception: likes not defined

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your code.

What do you think  `value : (0, 200),` does?

`value` would equal `20`.

The other issues you have is scoping issue. Looks like you have something going on with local variables and I am guessing you are treating asynchronous callbacks like they are synchronous.

I think what you are really after is just

```
function makeAGage( value ) {
    var g4 = new JustGage({
                id : "g4",
                value : (0, 200),
                min : 0,
                max : 500,
                title : "Facebook likes",
                showMinMax : false
            });
}
```

and you callback

```
function(data) {
    makeAGage(data[0].fan_count);
});
```

Comment: sorry i did an mistake: the origin function was value : 200, AND NOT value = (0, 200), sorry for that. The plan is now to set value : equal to value of likes set in the other function.

Comment: Which is what I showed. You probably needed to show more code. how the function is invoked and how you call the code that makes the JustGage.

Comment: thank you epascarello. The code for the gauge is from http://www.justgage.com. The value for var likes is coming from a separate js-file (see the code at the top)